# Twitter log in without Oauth, but with POST - Python;Requests

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to login to twitter by simulating a browser connection. (without any twitter APIs or the like)
Other websites seem to work with this code but twitter is returning me to the log in page with a 200...

```
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://twitter.com/'
user = 'user'
passw='test'
headers1 =  {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9\'*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'DNT':'1',
    'Host':'twitter.com',
    'Referer':'https://twitter.com',
    'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0',
}
inputTags = list()
keys = list()
authToken = ''

class GetAuthToken(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag == 'input':
            type_ = attrs[0]
            if type_[0] == 'type':
                 if type_[1] == 'hidden':
                     name = attrs[1]
                     if name[1] == 'authenticity_token':
                           value = attrs[2]
                           if value[0] == 'value':
                                 global authToken
                                 authToken = value[1]


s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers1
r = s.get(url)
html = r.text
parser = GetAuthToken()
parser.feed(html) #got authToken
payload = {
    'session[username_or_email]' : user,
    'session[password]' : passw,
    'remember_me' : '1',
    'return_to_ssl' : 'true',
    'scribe_log' : None,
    'redirect_after_login':'/',
    'authenticity_token':authToken
}
s.post(url,data=payload)
r2 = s.get(url)
print(r2.text)

s.close()
```

There must be a way to simulate the browser and actually get the page, is there anything other than POST I should be doing?

(I've looked at how firebug logs in and the POST data should be correct)

All help greatly appreciated,

Steve

Comment: I tried it and it returned me the home page of twitter.com when not logged in. What are you expecting your script to return? The home page after logging in?

Comment: Yes, a logged in page, which is usually also at twitter.com/

Comment: did u get it work? Is the code working?